# Gutenberg block: add a multi-select for posts

Tags: posts, wp-query, javascript, block-editor, react

I created a custom Gutenberg block with @wordpress/create-block.

I now have a dropdown where you can select a post, but I would like this to be a multi-select where you can select multiple posts. How can I achieve this?

This is what I have now in my edit.js:

```
const { useSelect } = wp.data;

const { pages } = useSelect( ( select ) => {
    const { getEntityRecords } = select( 'core' );

    // Query args
    const query = {
        status: 'publish',
        per_page: 100
    }

    return {
        pages: getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post', query ),
    }
} )

let options = [];
if( pages ) {
    options.push( { value: 0, label: 'Select a post' } )
    pages.forEach( ( page ) => {
        options.push( { value : page.id, label : page.title.rendered } )
    })
} else {
    options.push( { value: 0, label: 'Loading...' } )
}

  return (
        <div>
            <InspectorControls>
                <PanelBody 
                    title={ __( 'Post settings', 'example-block' )}
                    initialOpen={true}
                >
                    <PanelRow>
                        <fieldset>
                          <SelectControl label="Select a post" options={ options } />
                        </fieldset>
                    </PanelRow>
                </PanelBody>
            </InspectorControls>
        </div>
    );
```

Can I use for example FormTokenField for this?

Comment: I don't think core provides a way to do this, you'd need to build a component and handle the UI yourself. There is a component some colleagues of mine built that might be useful inspiration though: https://github.com/humanmade/block-editor-components/tree/main/src/components/PostPicker but it isn't a multiselect, it's a button that brings up a searchable modal dialog

Comment: What about FormTokenField? Is this something that could be used?

Comment: maybe but not on its own, as I said this isn't something that can be done with a component and a few flags, it's an involved task. Note that the code in your question doesn't scale, you'll run into performance issues and memory issues on large sites trying to fetch all the posts, both in the browser and on the server